# Regex to match any length number and decimal points at any position in the number

Tags: regex

I want to match patterns like the following:

```
1.234 < x < 33.34
14123 <= x < 55656
```

Basically, I want to match any numerals no matter how long, and an optional decimal no matter where it is in the numerals. I feel like `<,<=` is easy enough. However, I cannot figure out how to match the numbers.

Here is my regex that only matches the signs and "x": `(<=?)x(<=?)`

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I got the answer :

`\d+(?:.\d+)?( <=? )x( <=? )\d+(?:.\d+)?`

Comment: try this `\d+(?:\.\d+)?( <=? )x( <=? )\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: i found two mistakes in your regex. 1, don't use `\d*` before the `.` because it matches **zero** or more numbers. 2, `.` represents any charcater not a literal do.

Comment: Use Avinash Raj's pattern, as it allows both the `.` and remaining digits to be optional. Yours requires additional digits even if there is no `.`, meaning single digit numbers will fail to match, e.g. `1<x<2`.